# Objective C - "Duplicate declaration of method" compilation error

Tags: objective-c, methods, signature

I have this piece of code:

```
- (id) getSearchSuggestions:(NSString*)q;
- (NSOperationQueue*) getSearchSuggestions:(NSString*)q callback:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
- (id) getSearchSuggestions;
- (NSOperationQueue*) getSearchSuggestions:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
```

And I Xcode keeps showing me an error on the **last** line:

```
Duplicate declaration of method "getSearchSuggestions"
```

Why? It seems to me that the signatures are all different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This signature:

```
- (id) getSearchSuggestions:(NSString*)q;
```

Is identical to this signature:

```
- (NSOperationQueue*) getSearchSuggestions:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
```

All object pointers are `id`. So both of these are methods that take an object and return an object.

Examples of better names would be:

```
- (id)searchSuggestionsForQueryString:(NSString*)q; // Or ForTag, or whatever "q" is
- (NSOperationQueue*)searchOperationQueueForQuery:(NSString*)q callback:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
- (id)fetchSearchSuggestions;
- (NSOperationQueue*)searchOperationQueueWithCallback:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
```

It's not exactly clear why you return an operation queue here, but this is the kind of name you'd use for a method that did that.

Comment: Actually, it doesn’t matter that all object pointers are `id`. The error happens because of the selector, which doesn’t represent the whole of the signature — in particular, it doesn’t represent types. The same error would happen if it were, say, `float` instead of `NSString *`.

Comment: Good point. I focused on the OP's comment about signatures rather than the actual error message. His examples have the same signature, while taking a `float` would have a different one (though still a conflicting selector).

Answer (score 1):

Think of the corresponding selectors:

```
- (id) getSearchSuggestions:(NSString*)q;
getSearchSuggestions:

- (NSOperationQueue*) getSearchSuggestions:(NSString*)q callback:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
getSearchSuggestions:callback:

- (id) getSearchSuggestions;
getSearchSuggestions

- (NSOperationQueue*) getSearchSuggestions:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
getSearchSuggestions:
```

As you can see, the first and the last method have the same selector, hence the duplicate method declaration error. You need to disambiguate them by changing their names.

Answer (score 1):

it is because these two have the same selector:

```
- (id) getSearchSuggestions:(NSString*)q;
- (NSOperationQueue*) getSearchSuggestions:(id<UserDelegate>)callback;
```

you must choose unique names for selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to overload methods like in Java. Objective-C doesn't have this capability (it basically doesn't work well with Objective-C's more dynamic type system). In Objective-C, the selector for a method is the entirety of how it is identified. Think of it as a message: "Call the method named `getSearchSuggestions:` and give it these arguments." There can't be multiple methods in the class called `getSearchSuggestions:` because the selector is the only thing the message dispatch system has to determine which method is called.