# Duplicate declaration of method objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, function, overloading

This question may be duplicate of the [Objective C - "Duplicate declaration of method" compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374277/objective-c-duplicate-declaration-of-method-compilation-error)

But i am still confuse for why objective C dose not support the function Overloading / method overloading

Can any one tell me the proper reason for why this error occur?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Objective-C doesn't support method overloading?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444783/why-objective-c-doesnt-support-method-overloading)

Answer (score 4):

objective-C does not support method overloading, so you have to use different method names.

Comment: Thanks for answer me, but i want to know is there any reason for not supporting method overloading

Answer (score 4):

Simply because Objective-C doesn't support overloading. And besides it is highly recommended to include the types of the arguments in the function's name, whenever possible. Try `getTextFromTextView:` and `getTextFromTextField:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I want to tell you please check the *"How to [define method ?](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)"*, You can found in above link about multiple input method also. and this [one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocDefiningClasses.html) is for naming conventions of method in Objective C?

As per above we can know that your method have same name(Signature) as `getText:`

*In your case there are duplicated method you define which is not supported by objective C Compiler.*

Hope this one helpful to you.

Answer (score -1):

read this thread that why objective c does not suport method overloading

[Why Objective-C doesn't support method overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444783/why-objective-c-doesnt-support-method-overloading)

and this is apple discussion form
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/512569?start=0&tstart=0